# Adding an op in tensorflow in windows

Tags: python, c++, c, tensorflow

I am currently trying to optimise word2vec implementation of tensorflow, to get it to work like the original gensim word2vec implementation. However, the tutorial here

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/embedding/word2vec.py, 
requires that I first add a new op to tensorflow.

I have cloned the repository to my desktop, both the tensorflow/tensorflow-master and tensorflow/models-master in a directory named tensorflow.
I try to compile word2vec_ops.cc and word2vec_kernels.cc files (which define the implementation and the interface of the new op) located in models-master/tutorials/embeddings

It gives me following error message -

```
In file included from word2vec_kernels.cc:16:0:
tensorflow/core/framework/op.h:23:54: fatal error: 
tensorflow/core/framework/op_def_builder.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I also copied the tensorflow-master/tensorflow/ folder into models-master/tutorials/embedding/ so that all the required header files are in same directory (see the github repo for reference, I have the similar directory tree on windows : https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/core )

Original compiling procedure :

```
TF_CFLAGS=( $(python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(" 
".join(tf.sysconfig.get_compile_flags()))') )

TF_LFLAGS=( $(python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(" 
".join(tf.sysconfig.get_link_flags()))') )

g++ -std=c++11 -shared word2vec_ops.cc word2vec_kernels.cc -o 
word2vec_ops.so -fPIC ${TF_CFLAGS[@]} ${TF_LFLAGS[@]} -O2 - 
D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0
```

This sequence of commands does not work in windows terminal (obviously). So I also defined the flags within the code itself

```
flags.DEFINE_string("save_path", 'C:\Users\Desktop\log_dir\gensim\22', 
"Directory to write the model and "
                "training summaries.")
flags.DEFINE_string("train_data", 'cmpl.txt', "Training text file. "
                "E.g., unzipped file 
http://mattmahoney.net/dc/text8.zip.")
flags.DEFINE_string(
"eval_data", 'questions-words.txt', "File consisting of analogies of four 
tokens."
"embedding 2 - embedding 1 + embedding 3 should be close "
"to embedding 4."
"See README.md for how to get 'questions-words.txt'.")
```

, so I do not need to pass them onto sys.argv(), (so the first two 
commands are not required), and yet ,still using anaconda mingw, I am unable to build the dynamic library for the implementation.due to the error earliur mentioned

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution by using Windows subsytem for Linux. So, instead of dual-booting or a virtual environment,
On windows in the search box, type "turn windows features on/off" and check the box for -> windows subsystem for linux
Then windows asks you to restart the system, upon which you can install any relevant terminals (I installed Ubuntu 18.04) from the windows store.

Next, to the setup is extremely simple, you only setup the username and pwd, and you are good to go.

You can access any of the files on windows by

```
cd /mnt/c/
```

So, I loaded my working directory onto C drive and used the system, as Linux.
Though its a very roundabout solution, it works on an ad-hoc basis.